# How to prove the limit exists when I don't know how to evaluate it?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

The question says "prove the limit of $\frac{x^3+y^4}{|x|+|y|}$ exists when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.
"
Well I can use the epsilon delta definition when I know the answer to the limit.
I normally use a calculator for this case an online calculator says the limit is 0. So I used it. But how do I solve the limit myself?

Comment: If the limit exists, then regardless of which path one takes, the output limit must always be the same. In particular, set $y=0$, and let $x\to 0^+$ (i.e let $x>0$ and approach $0$). From here, it's clear that the limit, if it exists, must necessarily be $0$. So, now you have a guess for what the limit is, and you can try to prove it exists.

Comment: Oh so there isn't a direct trick to calculate it. We make a guess then prove our guess! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, one always has to start with a guess for the limit (in my comment it wasn't really a guess; it was a careful deduction for what the limit necessarily must equal if it exists; but yes in general one must guess). The $\epsilon,\delta$ is used to prove that your "guess" is correct ([see my remarks here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3794159/568204) for example).

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me a lot! :) thank you.

Comment: You can still prove the existence of the limit without knowing to which value it converges to. You could consider a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ which converges to $0$ and show that the sequence $f(x_n,y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. However the method peek-a-boo gave you is a far better method in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

We can assume that $x$ and $y$ are both less that $1$ in absolute value. The absolute value of your expression is
$$ \le \frac{|x|^3+y^4}{|x|+|y|} \le \frac{|x|^3+|y|^3}{|x|+|y|}.$$
The following limits go to $(0,0)$ for nonnegative $x$ and $y$:
$$\lim \frac{x^3+y^3}{x+y} \le \lim \frac{(x+y)^3}{x+y}=$$
$$ \lim (x+y)^2=0.$$